# Java method runs in Eclipse and compiled jar but not NetBeans

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans

I have a method that sends a request to a game server and receives player data back from the server.

When I run this code in Eclipse, it works properly and the server sends the correct data. It also works properly from the standalone jar.

If I run the same code in Netbeans, the remote server essentially rejects the request and sends "disconnect"

```
this.address = InetAddress.getByName(address);
this.connection = new DatagramSocket();

public byte[] sendStatus() throws IOException{
    //Construct the buffer from the command, then the PREFIX
    byte[] addOn = "rcon \"Password\" status".getBytes();
    byte[] toSend = new byte[addOn.length + PACKET_PREFIX.length];

    //Combine into one bytes array
    System.arraycopy(PACKET_PREFIX, 0, toSend, 0, PACKET_PREFIX.length);
    System.arraycopy(addOn, 0, toSend,PACKET_PREFIX.length, addOn.length);

    System.out.println(new String(toSend));
    //Make the toSend packet
    DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(toSend, toSend.length, this.address, 28960);

    //Now we send it
    this.connection.send(packet);

    //And receive the data.
    byte[] buffer = new byte[65536];
    DatagramPacket rec = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);

    this.connection.receive(rec);

    byte[] data = rec.getData();

    return data;
}
```

Any help is appreciated. The two lines above are defined elsewhere.

Comment: Debug both cases and make sure you get to the line that thrown the error with exactly the same values.

Comment: make sure it doesn't miss any external jars,if being used !